# LAMP Server, MYSQL, PuTTy

Tags: mysql, lamp, putty

I am connection to a LAMP Server trough PuTTY.

I have no idea if there is a GUI available so I'm doing this trough the CLI. The problem now is that I need certain fields from the database and I have no idea how the database looks since the lack of documentation.

How should I approach this. In the database there are 148 tables. Should I just go trough every table one at a time? Is there a smart way?

Thanks.

Comment: You can always install PHPMyAdmin. This is very easy if you use Ubuntu or Debian: `apt-get update` and `apt-get install phpmyadmin`. After this is done, go to `siteurl.com/phpmyadmin` and log in, and you'll have a GUI. If you'd rather do it through CLI, look into the `mysql` command.

Comment: It's not my server and I don't think I can install anything. How to find out what's installed/ version/ w/e etc. :)? I'll use this for now: rpm -qa --queryformat "%{GROUP} %{NAME}-%{VERSION}\n" | sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always install PHPMyAdmin, but if you don't have access to do so, you can try [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/). This installs on your computer, and you just put in your server info and connect

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of GUI tools available for MySQL, some that you normally install on the server and others that you run on your desktop, here's a short list:

MySQL Workbench - Official mysql gui tool with really nice features (especially coming to db design)

PHPMyAdmin - web based interface, can be installed on the server and reached through a web interface.

HeidiSQL (free, windows) - desktop app

SQLYog (lot's of features, costs money) - desktop app

Sequel Pro (free, slim and good for macosx) - desktop app

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the mysql-query browser for connect database.

Download link for window use : -> 
http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/query/